# Android- Upload image to Firebase under a specific user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, android-sharedpreferences

I am fairly new to Android and want to make an app that allows users to upload pictures using Firebase storage. After they log in, I made it so that their Uid gets sent to SharedPreferences, so that I can retrieve it in my imageupload activity later. I need it so that when the image gets sent to Firebase, it gets put under the folder of their userid.

This is my current login activity that retrieves the Uid:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (firebaseUser != null) {
                    String userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
                    sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putString("firebasekey", userId);
                    editor.commit();
```

And this is my imageupload activity:

```
sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String UserId = sharedPref.getString("firebasekey", "1");
    StorageReference storageRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference mountainsRef = storageRef.child("uploads/"+UserId+System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your actual problem yet. What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at my blog: http://engineering.letsnurture.com/firebase-storage/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go

```
String userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
UploadTask uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().child("newFolder").getReference(userUid).putBytes(yourPhotoToByteArray);
uploadTask
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
```

And to retrieve image

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("newFolder/" + userUid);
```

You can read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start) more about FirebaseCloudStorage. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) how to upload, and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) how to download them.

Comment: How do I put the image under the uid?

Comment: `FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(userUid)` is that what you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: When I save the image to Firebase in .child; How can I create a folder of that person's uid?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it will help you, i haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mozy below code should, when called launch intent to choose an image from gallery and upload it to firebase. Hope this helps.

```
private void updateImg() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select picture"), CHOOSE_IMAGE);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CHOOSE_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            // Display an error
            return;
        }


        // create an inputStream from the intent result we have just created
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = yourActivity.this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            uploadImageToFirebase(inputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void uploadImageToFirebase(InputStream rInputStream) {
    sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String UserId = sharedPref.getString("firebasekey", "1");
    StorageReference storageRef = 
    FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference mountainsRef = storageRef.child("uploads/"+UserId+System.currentTimeMillis());
    // running the task
    UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putStream(rInputStream);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // show error
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // do ui stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to upload a picture they take, not one that already exists in their gallery